# SproutCore GridView not scrolling

Tags: javascript, sproutcore

I wish to implement something similar to a wall of photos. Now, I implemented an SC.GridView and got it data from a server.

It displays a wall of photos, but it gets clipped near the bottom of the browser. To show a scrollbar (since I have 1000 + images), I put the whole thing in an SC.ScrollView by doing:

`SC.ScrollView.design({
    contentView: MyApp.GridView.design ({
      //code here
    })
 ]);`

How do I get the scroller to show up?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the problem was that my grid view was inside another view. The moment I pulled my grid view from another view, the scrollView appeared. >_<